# My javascript is not working but no error Laravel 6

Tags: javascript, php-7, laravel-6

I am now trying to use javascripts in my project.Can somebody please explain how exactly, can we make javascripts working on a Laravel project ?
all the code works except for the js party
it does not appear on the screen
Thanks
Here's my code :
**checkout.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')                             
@section('content')           
 //code                 
@endsection                 
@section('extra-js')
  
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.13.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
    <script>

            (function(){
            var form = document.querySelector('#paypal-payment-form');
            var client_token = "{{ $paypalToken }}";

            braintree.dropin.create({
              authorization: client_token,
              selector: '#bt-dropin',
              paypal: {
                flow: 'vault'
              }
            }, function (createErr, instance) {
              if (createErr) {
                console.log('Create Error', createErr);
                return;
              }

              // remove credit card option
              var elem = document.querySelector('.braintree-option__card');
              elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

              form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log('Request Payment Method Error', err);
                    return;
                  }

                  // Add the nonce to the form and submit
                  document.querySelector('#nonce').value = payload.nonce;
                  form.submit();
                });
              });
            });

        })();
    </script>
@endsection
```

and this is a part of my default.blade.php
**default.blade.php**

```
 @yield('content')
    @yield('extra-js')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: when you say "not working" ... does it run at all (put a console.log as the first statement to check)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` is jQuery. Are you loading jQuery in somewhere?

Comment: I add it just in case it wants to work but it doesn't work -Emiel Zuurbier

Comment: all the code works apart from the js party it does not appear on the screen -Jaromanda X